# ObjectNotExecutableError when running Pandasql query in Google Colab

Tags: sql, pandas, google-colaboratory, pandasql

I have a pandas dataframe called `df`.

Doing a standard SQL query using `pandasql`. However, it gives me the following error:

`ObjectNotExecutableError: Not an executable object: 'SELECT * FROM df'`

```
from pandasql import sqldf
q1 = """SELECT * FROM df"""
sqldf(q1, globals())
```

Answer (score 7):

in my case pip install SQLAlchemy==1.4.46 and restart kernel solved the issue.

Comment: that didnt work because i am using `from pandasql import sqldf`? are you using a different package?

Comment: I don't even need to restart the kernel. Something must be wrong with 2.0.23 version (on 29/11/2023). Downgrading it to 1.4.46 helped.